# Convert DataGridViewRow to String

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have a `DataGridViewRow` and I want to convert it to a string in the format mentioned below:

`cell[0].ToString()+"\t"+cell[1].Tostring()+"\t"+...+cell[n].ToString()`

In fact I want a string which has the string values of each cell in `DataGridViewRow` and a `\t` between them.

what is the best clean and readable way? Is using loop and checking the condition is the only way? the first solution would be to add each cell with `\t` to a temp string and then remove the last character of the temp string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever it's loops, LINQ comes to the rescue.

```
string.Join("\t", cell.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Comment: row.Cells. you also used cell in the question, I thought you knew. also, you might need row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(...) if it's not a generic collection.

Comment: it should be `temp = string.Join("\t", row.Cells.Cast<DataGridViewCell>().Select(c => c.Value.ToString()).ToArray())`

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the DataGridViewRow class:

```
    public static string Format(this DataGridViewRow row, string separator)
    {
        string[] values = new string[row.Cells.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            values[i] = row.Cells[i].Value + "";
        return string.Join(separator, values);
    }
```

Then:

```
string msg = row.Format("\t");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string output = row.Cells.Aggregate("", (a, current) => a + current + "\t");
```

Comment: Adding lots of strings is bad practice.

Comment: If you have a lot of strings (or a tight loop), this is correct. Otherwise, not so much; in this case it would be premature optimisation.