# C# DataGridView.Rows.ToString()

Tags: c#, string, datagridview, tostring

I am trying to store the values of each of my rows in a string.

If I try to do `DataGridView.Rows.ToString()` I get

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRowCollection
```

Not even close to what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using the default grid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert DataGridViewRow to String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534222/convert-datagridviewrow-to-string)

Comment: You need to loop through each cell inside the `RowCollection`.

Comment: @Ezi : I don't know what you're trying to ask. I have a DataGridView on my form and it is full of columns and data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for something on a per row basis.  If so, I suggest the following.

```
  private static IEnumerable<string> GetRowValues(this DataGridView dgv)
  {
     var list = new List<string>(dgv.Rows.Count);
     foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
     {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        {
           sb.Append(cell.ToString());
        }
        list.Add(sb.ToString());
     }
     return list.AsReadOnly();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int row=0; row<DataGridView.Rows.Count; row++)
{
    for(int col=0; col < DataGridView.Columns.Count; col++)
    {
        sb.Append(DataGridView.Row[row][col].ToString());
    }
}
sb.ToString(); // that will give you the string you desire
```

*EDIT* I didn't run this through to check that it runs but it should at least give you a starting point. Also, this will give you all rows. If you want just one row, change the variable row to the row number you need (keep in mind that it is zero-based).

Comment: +1 for using StringBuilder and giving the OP the option of all rows or a single row.

Answer (score 2):

Use the for each statement to iterate through each row in the Datagridview.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow datarow in dataGridView.Rows)
{
    string col1 = datarow.Cells["Col1"].Value.ToString();
    string col2 = datarow.Cells["Col2"].Value.ToString();
    string col3 = datarow.Cells["Col3"].Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach(Var row in DataGridView.Rows)
{
    Foreach(Var cell in row.Cells)
    {
        Var str = cell; // this is the string you want
    }
}
```

Something like the code above. Excuse the formatting typed on iPad.